# Using Postman Mock Server on-premise

Tags: postman

Due to data protection, I am not allowed to send any data to the Postman cloud and using https://...mock.pstmn.io when mocking APIs.
Is it possible to use Postman on-premise by using a tool that makes it possible to mock an API locally on one of our server without using the Postman cloud? Or maybe any other ideas how to avoid a problem like that?

Thx in advance for your answers and help!

I did not find anything like that on google but I hope for the best ;)

Comment: You can't use the Postman mock service, as this is run in the Postman Cloud.  However, you should be able to search for other mocking services that you can install locally.